# JiaoZiVideoPlayer player doesn't play anything

Tags: android, jiaozivideoplayer

I imported this library:

```
compile 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.10'
```

https://github.com/lipangit/JiaoZiVideoPlayer

---

my view:

```
<cn.jzvd.JZVideoPlayerStandard
    android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

`onCreate()` function:

```
JZVideoPlayerStandard jzVideoPlayerStandard = (JZVideoPlayerStandard) findViewById(R.id.videoplayer);
jzVideoPlayerStandard.setUp("https://hw20.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/7fd1cf80cc0f254e98f8785d783bf10810811179-144p__81878.mp4", 
                            JZVideoPlayerStandard.SCREEN_WINDOW_NORMAL, 
                            "-");
```

but it not play my video and it just show a animation loading.

where is my wrong?

Comment: why don't you ask it on the github?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work using this:

In gradle:

```
implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.3.1'
```

In xml,

```
<cn.jzvd.JzvdStd
        android:id="@+id/video_player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

In java:

```
JzvdStd jzvdStd = (JzvdStd) rootView.findViewById(R.id.video_player);
jzvdStd.setUp("https://hw20.cdn.asset.aparat.com/aparat-video/7fd1cf80cc0f254e98f8785d783bf10810811179-144p__81878.mp4"
        , "How It Works" , Jzvd.SCREEN_WINDOW_NORMAL);
//jzvdStd.thumbImageView.setImage("http://p.qpic.cn/videoyun/0/2449_43b6f696980311e59ed467f22794e792_1/640");
```

Perhaps the version is different from yours (6.2.10)